# super() gives an error in Python 2

Tags: python, subclass, super

I just started learning Python and I don't quite understand where the problem in this code is. I have a base class Proband with two methods and I want to create a subclass Gesunder and I want to override the attributes idn,artefakte.

```
import scipy.io
class Proband:
  def __init__(self,idn,artefakte):
    self.__idn = idn
    self.artefakte = artefakte
  def getData(self):
    path = 'C:\matlab\EKGnurbild_von Proband'+ str(self.idn)
    return scipy.io.loadmat(path)
  def __eq__(self,neueProband):
    return self.idn == neueProband.idn and self.artefakte == neueProband.artefakte



class Gesunder(Proband):
  def __init__(self,idn,artefakte,sportler):
    super().__init__(self,idn,artefakte)
    self.__sportler = sportler

hans = Gesunder(2,3,3)
```

Comment: Please reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code. In python 2:

1. `super()` takes 2 arguments: the class name, and the instance
2. in order to use `super()`, the base class must inherit from `object`

So your code becomes:

```
import scipy.io

class Proband(object):
    def __init__(self,idn,artefakte):
        self.__idn = idn
        self.artefakte = artefakte
    def getData(self):
        path = 'C:\matlab\EKGnurbild_von Proband'+ str(self.idn)
        return scipy.io.loadmat(path)
    def __eq__(self,neueProband):
        return self.idn == neueProband.idn and self.artefakte == neueProband.artefakte

class Gesunder(Proband):
    def __init__(self,idn,artefakte,sportler):
        super(Gesunder, self).__init__(idn,artefakte)
        self.__sportler = sportler

hans = Gesunder(2,3,3)
```

Note the the call to `super(Gesunder, self).__init__` does not have `self` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, `super()` on its own is invalid. Instead, you must use `super(ClassName, self)`.

```
super(Gesunder, self).__init__(self, idn, artefakte)
```

Comment: Thats what I previously thought but it still doesnt compile intead it gives an error: TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: @Frodon's answer is right - you must ensure `Proband` inherits `object`.

Answer (score 0):

The `super()` call should be modified to :

```
super(Gesunder, self).__init__(self, idn, artefakte)
```